# AngularJS: display wrong data because of https request latency

Tags: angularjs, https, latency

**Newbie :)**

I have a filter in my AngularJS page with many options: View all, View x, View y, ...
I use `$http.post` to post the filter's state to the api and then get the corresponding data.

Ex: `'/api/filter/Get'`

The problem comes when I click on *View all* option and then **quickly click on another option**. Ex: *View x* option. If the first request need `1s` to get the data back and the second one needs only `0.3s` -> at first the page will display the data of option *View x* and right after that it will display the data of option *View all* -> Wrong because the state of filter at this time is: *View x*.

Any solution for this issue? thanks :)

It's great if we can have the good performance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of solutions to the issue

- Disable the filter as soon as an Ajax request fires.
- Make the user actually press a button to filter the request, so they can change their mind as much as they want before committing to the request.
- Show a nice loading *'page'* that hides the filters
- Don't perform the second Ajax request until the other one has completed.

I could list solutions all day, there are plenty of different ways of handling this situation, you need to pick one that is right for your site.